# localhost and remote host access angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with a button and a form. Initially only the button will be visible, **form is hidden using ng-hide condition** (link to third party website) , on clicking that button you will be redirected to another page for log-in. After log-in my API redirects to my original page but instead of ,

**localhost:8443/mypage/mypage.html** (where i set a variable as true once log-in is success to display the form)

callback is for

**john-1234:8443/mypage/mypage.html** (the variable is not set true)

Is there any **difference between calling as localhost:8443 and john-1234:8443**. Does it have any impact on variables evaluated by controller.

Please help me. Sorry if this is a silly doubt. But i am new to this.

Comment: by `callback` do you mean you're getting login information from a different domain (through REST), or are you actually redirecting to another site after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost means this computer and resolved as 127.0.0.1 as you may already know.

john-1234 will not be resolved then as it does not mean this computer for your system.
So your controller will not receive the variables. Possibly you have a test environment. If you proceed with production environment, then you would be able to redirect to an exact URL which will perfectly work.